# Using setText in a switch statement

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a Memory type game. Everything is fine except it doesn't display the second card if it is not a match. This is because it does not perform the setText() until after the switch statement completes, but I have it switching the card back in the compare before it exits the switch. I thought I could use setText() and put a couple second wait before the compare but that is not the case. Is there a better way I can do this or a way to force the setText() to happen immediately instead of when exiting the switch?

```
public class Game extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private Button buttonA1;
    private Button buttonA2;
    private Button buttonA3;
    private Button buttonA4;
    private Button buttonB1;
    private Button buttonB2;
    private Button buttonB3;
    private Button buttonB4;
    private Button buttonC1;
    private Button buttonC2;
    private Button buttonC3;
    private Button buttonC4;
    private Button choice1;
    private Button choice2;
    private Button reset;
    private Model model;
    private int cardNum=1;
    private int turn=1;
    private TextView turnDisplay;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_concentration);
        start();

        context = getApplicationContext();

        model = new Model();
        buttonA1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonA1.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonA2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        buttonA2.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonA3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        buttonA3.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonA4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
        buttonA4.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonB1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        buttonB1.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonB2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        buttonB2.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonB3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        buttonB3.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonB4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
        buttonB4.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonC1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        buttonC1.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonC2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        buttonC2.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonC3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        buttonC3.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonC4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        buttonC4.setOnClickListener(this);
        reset= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
        reset.setOnClickListener(this);
        turnDisplay= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.turnView);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button1:
                buttonA1.setText(model.entityList.get(0));

                if(cardNum ==1)
                {
                    choice1=buttonA1;
                    cardNum++;
                }
                else
                {
                    choice2=buttonA1;
                    compCard(choice1, choice2);
                    turn++;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                buttonA2.setText(model.entityList.get(1));

                if(cardNum ==1)
                {
                    choice1=buttonA2;
                    cardNum++;
                }
                else
                {
                    choice2=buttonA2;
                    compCard(choice1, choice2);
                    turn++;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                buttonA3.setText(model.entityList.get(2));
                if(cardNum ==1)
                {
                    choice1=buttonA3;
                    cardNum++;
                }
                else
                {
                    choice2=buttonA3;
                    compCard(choice1, choice2);
                    turn++;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button10:
                buttonA4.setText(model.entityList.get(9));
                if(cardNum ==1)
                {
                    choice1=buttonA4;
                    cardNum++;
                }
                else
                {
                    choice2=buttonA4;
                    compCard(choice1, choice2);
                    turn++;
        }
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                buttonB1.setText(model.entityList.get(3));
                if(cardNum ==1)
                {
                    choice1=buttonB1;
                    cardNum++;
                }
                else
                {
                    choice2=buttonB1;
                    compCard(choice1, choice2);
                    turn++;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button5:
                buttonB2.setText(model.entityList.get(4));
                if(cardNum ==1)
                {
                    choice1=buttonB2;
                    cardNum++;
                }
                else
                {
                    choice2=buttonB2;
                    compCard(choice1, choice2);
                    turn++;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button6:
                buttonB3.setText(model.entityList.get(5));
                if(cardNum ==1)
                {
                    choice1=buttonB3;
                    cardNum++;
                }
                else
                {
                    choice2=buttonB3;
                    compCard(choice1, choice2);
                    turn++;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button11:
                buttonB4.setText(model.entityList.get(10));
                if(cardNum ==1)
                {
                    choice1=buttonB4;
                    cardNum++;
                }
                else
                {
                    choice2=buttonB4;
                    compCard(choice1, choice2);
                    turn++;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button7:
                buttonC1.setText(model.entityList.get(6));
                if(cardNum ==1)
                {
                    choice1=buttonC1;
                    cardNum++;
                }
                else
                {
                    choice2=buttonC1;
                    compCard(choice1, choice2);
                    turn++;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button8:
                buttonC2.setText(model.entityList.get(7));
                if(cardNum ==1)
                {
                    choice1=buttonC2;
                    cardNum++;
                }
                else
                {
                    choice2=buttonC2;
                    compCard(choice1, choice2);
                    turn++;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button9:
                buttonC3.setText(model.entityList.get(8));
                if(cardNum ==1)
                {
                    choice1=buttonC3;
                    cardNum++;
                }
                else
                {
                    choice2=buttonC3;
                    compCard(choice1, choice2);
                    turn++;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button12:
                buttonC4.setText(model.entityList.get(11));
                if(cardNum ==1)
                {
                    choice1=buttonC4;
                    cardNum++;
                }
                else
                {
                    choice2=buttonC4;
                    compCard(choice1, choice2);
                    turn++;
                }
                break;
            //resets the game
            case R.id.button13:
                finish();
                Music.stop(this);
                Intent x=new Intent(this, Game.class);
                startActivity(x);
                break;
        }

    }
    private void compCard(Button choice1, Button choice2) {
        //gets if the 2 cards match

        turnDisplay.setText(turn+" ");
        if(model.answerMap.get(choice1.getText())==choice2.getText()||
                model.answerMap.get(choice2.getText())==choice1.getText())
        {

            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
          //  choice1.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
          //  choice2.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
            choice1.setBackgroundColor(color.black);
            choice2.setBackgroundColor(color.white);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, ""+choice1.getText() + " and " + choice2.getText() + " are a match",duration);
           // Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(context, "Boom Headshot!", duration);
            toast.show();
            cardNum=1;
        }
        else
        {

            int duration=Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, ""+choice1.getText() + " and " + choice2.getText() + " are not a match ",duration);
            toast.show();
            choice1.setText("Match");
            choice2.setText("Match");
            cardNum=1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you remember the text of the choices (String) and compare that rather than comparing the buttons? Then your comparison function is simply `if (string1.equals(string2))`.

Comment: Even if I compare the text it does not help me show the value of the second card before the compare function.